# How to add null value to field Many2one from data file Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I want to add a new category of Salary Structure by data file. Here is my current code

```
   <record id="MEALS" model="hr.salary.rule.category">
        <field name="name">Meals</field>
        <field name="code">MEALS</field>
        <field name="parent_id" eval=""></field>
    </record>
```

All I need is a category with no parent category but with these code parent category of it is **Base for new structures**. I've tried with evals="0", evals = " " or remove field parent_id out of .How can I add null value into this field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is a little weird .AFAIK If you don't include the `parent_id` field, it should work and have a null value because that field doesn't have a default value on it. (Except you've extended the model and added a `default` on that field).

The only fields where null values don't work in the Odoo ORM are `Integer` and `float` fields. (That's the reason they always have an initial value of 0 or 0.0 in a form view).

quoting the docs:

> **field**
>
> Each record can be composed of field tags, defining values to
>   set when creating the record. A record with no field will use all
>   default values (creation) or do nothing (update).
>
> A field has a mandatory name attribute, the name of the field to set,
>   and various methods to define the value itself:
>
> **Nothing**
>
> if no value is provided for the field, an implicit False will
>   be set on the field. Can be used to clear a field, or avoid using a
>   default value for the field.

Try this `<field name="parent_id" />` or `<field name="parent_id" eval="False"` />

If the above don't work then double check your codebase and make sure you're not setting any default value on the field.

Comment: you 're right, it has default value for parent_id field, I changed it by inherit model hr.payroll.structure and change default value to False :
`parent_id = fields.Many2one(default=False)`